# Plotting communities with python igraph

Tags: python, graph, igraph, modularity, decomposition

I have a graph `g` in python-igraph. I can get a `VertexCluster` community structure with the following:

```
community = g.community_multilevel()
```

`community.membership` gives me a list of the group membership of all the vertices in the graph.

My question is really simple but I haven't found a python-specific answer on SO. How can I plot the graph with visualization of its community structure? Preferably to PDF, so something like

```
layout = g.layout("kk")
plot(g, "graph.pdf", layout=layout) # Community detection?
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass your VertexClustering object directly to the plot function; it will automatically plot the underlying graph instead and select colors automatically for the clusters. The desired layout can be specified in the layout=... keyword argument as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut!

Answer (score 10):

A nice way to plot the communities could be the following using `mark_groups`:

---

**Example**:

```
from igraph import *
import random
random.seed(1)


g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(30,0.3)
comms = g.community_multilevel()


plot(comms, mark_groups = True)
```

---

This results in the following:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the following error when I try this:


'TypeError: plotting not available'.


Can you clarify for me how to bypass this? Your graph seems really useful.

Comment: hello. The error that you get is related to some dependencies that Igraph is using for plotting. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45416251/5025009

Comment: That didn't help, however for anyone thats interested I found the solution was installing Micsrosoft Visual C++ 14.0, and installing the Pycairo wheel file located here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.     Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: Hi Seralouk, I'd really appreciate if you could have a look at my post in the link below. Cheers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102350/python-remove-overlapping-communities-in-igraph-plot

Answer (score 9):

Vertices remain ordered in the `layout`, `graph`, and `VertexCluster`, so you can do something like this:

Find the number of communities in the community structure:

```
>>> max(community.membership)
10
```

Then create a list/dictionary with `max + 1` unique colors (probably not manually like below):

```
>>> color_list = [
...     'red',
...     'blue',
...     'green',
...     'cyan',
...     'pink',
...     'orange',
...     'grey',
...     'yellow',
...     'white',
...     'black',
...     'purple'
... ]
```

Then, using list comprehension, create a list containing the colors for each vertex based on the group membership of that vertex and assign that to `vertex_color`:

```
plot(g, "graph.png", layout=layout,
     vertex_color=[color_list[x] for x in community.membership])
```

Result (It's so pretty!)

[image: graph]