# How to cluster a graph using python igraph

Tags: python, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

I've been using python igraph to try to make an easier time of generating and analyzing graphs. My code below generates a random graph of 50 nodes and clusters it:

```
from igraph import *
import random as rn

g = Graph()

size = 50

g.add_vertices(size)

vert = []

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        test = rn.randint(0,5)
        if j >= i or test is not 0:
            continue
        g.add_edges([(i,j)])

#layout = g.layout("kk")
#plot(g, layout = layout)

#dend = VertexDendrogram(graph=g, optimal_count=10)

clust = VertexClustering(g, membership=range(size))
#clust = dend.as_clustering()

c = clust.cluster_graph()

plot(clust, mark_groups=True)

layout = c.layout("kk")
#plot(c, layout = layout)
```

However, I'm not sure if this is correct, since the result has every single node as its own, isolated cluster. I am assuming this is somehow related to `membership`, the required parameter of VertexClustering, because I really don't understand what it means or why it is required.

Here is what [the terse documentation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.clustering.VertexClustering-class.html#__init__) says:

> the membership list. The length of the list must be equal to the number of vertices in the graph. If None, every vertex is assumed to belong to the same cluster.

And doesn't explain what I am supposed to set `membership` to in order to get a normal regular clustering.

Alternatively I tried using the `VertexDendrogram` as seen in the two commented lines of code. However, running this comes up with this runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sma_hw6_goedeke.py", line 22, in <module>
    dend = VertexDendrogram(graph=g, optimal_count=10)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

This is because `VertexDendrogram` requires the parameter `merges`. However, once again I have no clue what `merges` is supposed to be set to or why it is required. [The documentation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.clustering.VertexDendrogram-class.html#__init__) again says almost nothing:

> merges - the merges performed given in matrix form.

And I have no clue what that is. So what should I do to this code to get a normal, regular clustering for my random graph I can experiment with?

Comment: is there anything wrong with what i said?

Comment: `VertexClustering` is what it says it is, which, however, is not what you think it is. You think that it **computes** a vertex clustering (which is not unreasonable given the name of the class). However, as far as I can tell, the intent of the object is to **store/represent** a clustering that has already been computed elsewhere. For example, `igraph.Graph.clusters` returns a `VertexClustering` object. There are several community detection algorithms implemented in igraph, e.g. `igraph.Graph.community_optimal_modularity`, which return a `membership` assignment.

Comment: Use community detection functions and also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44881027/5025009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand by my original assessment that the documentation for `igraph` is maddeningly too terse.

The function I actually needed for what I am doing is `igraph.Graph.community_fastgreedy()`. In general, it seems all the functions that run a clustering algorithm all start with "community" in their name.

Comment: You can't be angry at somebody who gives you tons of stuff for free. Also, I am sure that Tamas will gladly accept pull requests that improve the docs: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  i have node from 0 to 4 so my membership list will be [0,0,0,1,1] implying node 0 to 2 belongs to cluster 0 and 3&4 belong to cluster one the list [0,0,0,1,1] will be membership list it will be used here is the usage of membership list as an example the code will create list of clusters as i have told above

```
import igraph
cls=igraph.Clustering([0,0,0,1,1])
```